# What is the default height of an HTML button?

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome, macos-mojave

I want to make my button height just a slight bit bigger than the default, but I don't know what the default is. I want to make it dynamic, preferably using % or vh/vw, so that it looks good on every device. I also want to know the %/vw/vh that is default.

I used chrome to find the height of the body tag, in relation to the button height, and then I set the button height to 9vh with css, but this didn't work, the body's height just increased. I then set the body height to 100%, but this didn't make a difference.

My code:

```css
.choice{
    width: calc(50vw - 12px);
    height: 25vh;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1em;
    font-size: 3.5vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

button, input[type="submit"]{
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #0099FF;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 2px solid #0099FF;
  margin: 2px;
  height: 9vh;

}

button:hover, input[type="submit"]:hover{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #000000;
}
```

I expected it to look the same as it would when the code would be like this ( I removed the height attribute in the `button, input[type="submit"]` section, but the buttons were extremely large instead!:

```css
.choice{
    width: calc(50vw - 12px);
    height: 25vh;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1em;
    font-size: 3.5vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

button, input[type="submit"]{
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #0099FF;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 2px solid #0099FF;
  margin: 2px; /* height used to be specified below */

}

button:hover, input[type="submit"]:hover{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: button are inline element so you will face issue with vertical alignment and font-size .. try to add `line-height:0` to the body to correctly see the height of the button

Comment: But I need to align text to center... That requires line-height to be size of text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help but think that this is a poorly posed question.

- Why do you want the button height to be "slightly bigger than default"? Presumably, you'd either want a fixed height, or a dynamic height that responds to the screen size. I fail to understand why you'd want an arbitrary size based upon HTML's default values. The default height of the button will be dependent on the font size anyways.
- If you don't set a body height, then it will be determined by the size of it's children. If you have a body tag with so set height, and then add a button with 9vh, your body will also be 9vh.

Edit:

If you're aiming to have the button have dynamic height based upon the body, then you need to set a body height, and then set the button's height to a percentage of its parent. E.g. body height set to "100vh", and button height set to "70%" or something to that effect.

Comment: Yes, you should edit the question. I'll edit my response to better answer your updated question.

Comment: Okay, changed the starting part

Comment: I want it as a %/vh/vw answer, not an absolute answer (preferably)

Comment: Edited my response

Comment: I added `body{height: 100%}`, I just haven't showed it in the code. This is what most of the topics similar to this on stack overflow told me to do, but it didn't make any visible differences.

Comment: Well, if you're really stuck on a percentage, then you can just set the html element to 100% first, and then set the body to 100% as well. That should make it fill the viewport in terms of height. 100vh is also a valid option.

Comment: Thank you, setting the html height to 100% worked! Now it looks so nice, plus it will look similar on all devices (In some old code it looked really nice on my computer, but it looked HORRIBLE on iPad. The buttons were **way** to big.)

Comment: Yeah, generally speaking, setting dynamic heights for elements like buttons is probably inadvisable anyways. Regardless, you'll need to set breakpoints and create some responsive styling to account for tablets/mobile.